# How do I fix this nested build object association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Question & Answer model -- similar to SO.

What I want to do is on my question#Show page, I would like for the user to be able to add their answer and have it be associated with that question and the user record.

This is what I have:

`Questions#Show view`:

```
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <%= render partial: "answers/form", locals: {answer: @question.answers.build(user: current_user)} %>
        </div>
```

In my `Answers#_Form`:

```
<%= simple_form_for(answer) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :body %>
  </div>

  <div id="new-post-submission-button">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my `question#show` controller:

```
def show
end
```

This is my `answer#create` controller:

```
  def create
    @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @answer.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Answer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @answer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is `answer_params`

```
  private
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def answer_params
      params.require(:answer).permit(:body, :user_id, :question_id)
    end
```

Yet once I submit something in my answer form, it creates a brand new record (not the one that the `render partial` call built.

Here is the initial record - which I got from `pry` on the actual rendered `_form.html.erb` partial:

```
[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fe931ec9768>>)> answer
=> #<Answer:0x007fe9385ec3a0 id: nil, body: nil, user_id: 1538, question_id: 4, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Yet this is what gets submitted and created in the db:

```
[117] pry(main)> Answer.last
  Answer Load (2.5ms)  SELECT  "answers".* FROM "answers" ORDER BY "answers"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Answer:0x007f87073772c0
 id: 48,
 body: "Does this one with user_id: 1538 and question_id: 4 get submitted?",
 user_id: nil,
 question_id: nil,
 created_at: Mon, 16 May 2016 07:49:58 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Mon, 16 May 2016 07:49:58 UTC +00:00>
```

Note the `user_id` and `question_id` are different in both (because once the submit is done, it creates a brand new record rather than using the one that was passed to it via `locals`).

What's the best way to approach what I am trying to do in the most Railsy-way?

**Edit 1**

Here are the params inspected in the `Answer#Create` action:

```
[1] pry(#<AnswersController>)> answer_params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"body"=>"Does this one with user_id: 1538 and question_id: 4 get submitted?"} permitted: true>
[2] pry(#<AnswersController>)> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NYMYT9K2AhLQ7seiYLr01ir/udTDbjmaBEsnEXLTSl/kcZg08f6L+mJW9G/kHMQaODmQhxisfn6Xm3OGMdGcfQ==", "answer"=><ActionController::Parameters {"body"=>"Does this one with user_id: 1538 and question_id: 4 get submitted?"} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Create Answer", "controller"=>"answers", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
[3] pry(#<AnswersController>)> @answer
=> nil
[4] pry(#<AnswersController>)> params[:answer]
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"body"=>"Does this one with user_id: 1538 and question_id: 4 get submitted?"} permitted: false>
[5] pry(#<AnswersController>)> answer_params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"body"=>"Does this one with user_id: 1538 and question_id: 4 get submitted?"} permitted: true>
```

**Edit 2**

`Question#New`

```
  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end
```

`Answer#New`

```
  def new
    @answer = Answer.new
  end
```

Comment: Can you inspect the `params` in the `create` action and post the output?

Comment: @Pravan Done. Refresh question.

Comment: try adding  `@question = Question.find "id" ` into your Question#show action

Comment: @AmolUdage That is already included in the `set_question` private method in my `QuestionsController`, and that is assigned to each action like so: `before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

Comment: Please add the code for the controller's `new` action in the question, as well.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out.

In my form, I added these hidden fields:

```
  <%= f.input :question_id, as: :hidden %>
  <%= f.input :user_id, as: :hidden %>
```

Then in my `Answers#Create` action, I simply did this:

```
question = Question.find(answer_params[:question_id])
user = User.find(answer_params[:user_id])
@answer = question.answers.create(user: user, question: question, body: answer_params[:body])
```

Because I eventually figured out that once I pass them in via hidden fields, they are permitted like so:

```
[5] pry(#<AnswersController>)> answer_params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"body"=>"This is a test submission.", "user_id"=>"1535", "question_id"=>"4"} permitted: true>
```

Now it all works like a charm!